# Why does fill in geom_histogram spill over into the wrong bins?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize a grade distribution by points on an exam with geom_historgram, while filling with the letter grade (A, B, C, D, F). For some reason, the fill color is spilling over into the wrong categories. I've checked the letter grade column against the points and it seems correct.

It is for a large class, so I trimmed the data to as few grades as possible that would reproduce a similar result.

I've used ifelse to create letter grades for the associated points. For example, A = 90 - 100, B = 80 - 79.99. Then I create the histogram with a letter grade fill, but part of the "B" bin shows up with "A" fill and part of the "C" bin has "B" fill.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(c(90.0, 40.4, 54.8, 86.0, 60.8, 78.4, 68.4, 59.2, 92.0, 64.4, 
                       42.4, 90.8, 83.2, 77.2, 85.2, 45.2, 56.0, 77.6, 73.6, 86.8,
                       66.0, 80.0, 90.0, 74.0, 77.6))
colnames(df1)<-c("grade")
df1$LetterGrade<- ifelse(df1$grade<60, "F",
ifelse(df1$grade>=60 & df1$grade<70,"D",
ifelse(df1$grade>=70 & df1$grade<80,"C",
ifelse(df1$grade>=80 & df1$grade<90,"B","A"))))

ggplot(df1, aes(x=grade, fill = LetterGrade)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))
```

[image: histogramresult]

I've tried adding bins = 10, but I get a similar result. I would like for each fill to correctly represent the letter grade. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `closed="left"`

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=grade, fill = LetterGrade)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 100, by = 10), closed="left") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))
```

[image]

otherwise the bins are `a < x <= b` and since you want to include the left side in the bin, you want `a <= x < b` which you can get with `closed="left"`. See `?geom_histogram` for more info.